# Convert.ToDateTime causes exception with a different culture only when passing sql server default time

Tags: asp.net, sql-server-2008, c#-4.0

In my c# codes, I used to use `Convert.ToDateTime(mydate)`. Until then the default format that successfully converted the string datetime was `MM/dd/yyyy`. Lately, my currentCulture was set as `<globalization uiCulture="en-GB" culture="en-GB"/>`. This made the default datetime format for string date conversions as `dd/MM/yyyy`. In my application, there are many places where I use `Convert.ToDateTime(dateAsFromSQL)` to try and convert direct sql server dates. But there, sql server default datetime format is `MM/dd/yyyy`.

I could use `DateTime.Parse` or `DateTime.ParseExact` or I could use the datetime format in sql server as `Convert(nvarchar, datetimefield, 103)` which produces the datetime format as `dd/MM/yyyy`. For me, changing the current procedures and codes is literally too much time consuming.

Is there any way that I can go around this situation without throwing an error?

Comment: Why do you use `Convert.ToDateTime` if the database field already is a datetime?

Comment: @adrianm The sql query is returned to a `DataTable` to retrieve data. To get a particular date from that `DataTable` field, I use `Convert.ToDateTime(dt.Rows[0]["DateField"])`

Comment: Still don't understand why you need to convert it via string. Wouldn't `(DateTime)dt.Rows[0]["DateField"]` work?

Comment: I doubt if `dt.Rows[0]["DateField"]' is in the format MM/dd/yyyy and parsing to DateTime expects format dd/MM/yyyy the compiler takes it as an error. As I've told, I have changed the culture.

Comment: So it is not really a date field in the database? It is just a string field which happens to contain something formatted as a date.

Comment: Ofcourse it is a datefield. My problem is I get a `FormatException` when I change the culture.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/38941/discussion-between-nisha-and-adrianm)